# Describing pixel format information in C++ in a way that is usable at both compile-time and runtime

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a library that does operations on pixels. The pixels can by in many different formats. I am looking for an effective way to describe the formats in the library API (internally and externally).

For some classes the pixel format is a **template argument**, for others it is a **runtime argument**. So the pixel formats need to be usable both runtime (as constructor or function argument) and compile time (as template argument). I want to **describe the pixel formats only once**.

What I have now is something like this:

```
enum class color_space : uint8_t { rgb, cmyk /* , etc... */ };

struct pixel_layout {
    color_space space;
    uint8_t channels;
    /* etc... */
};

template <color_space ColorSpace, uint8_t Channels /* etc.. */>
struct pixel_type {
    static constexpr color_space space = ColorSpace;
    static constexpr uint8_t channels = Channels;
    /* etc... */

    static constexpr pixel_layout layout() {
        return {space, channels /* , etc... */ };
    }
};

struct rgb  : public pixel_type<color_space::rgb, 3 /* , etc... */ > {};
struct rgba : public pixel_type<color_space::rgb, 4 /* , etc... */ > {};
```

This works fairly well. I can use these as runtime and compile time arguments:

```
template <class PixelType>
class image { };

struct transform {
    transform(const pixel_layout from, const pixel_layout to)
        : from(from), to(to) { /* ... */ }

    pixel_layout from;
    pixel_layout to;
};
```

Also convert from compile-time type to runtime type:

```
transform(rgb::layout(), rgba::layout());
```

**However**, duplicating and storing the `pixel_layout` details of the pixel types whenever they are used at runtime seems silly to me. Conceptually, all the program should need is an ID/address/reference to a specific `pixel_type` and a way to retrieve the associated properties (color space, channels, etc) at both compile time and runtime.

Also, if I want to get a derived property from a pixel type, I need to implement it on `pixel_layout` if I want to avoid duplicating logic. Then to use it at compile time, I need to go from `pixel_type<...>` class to `pixel_layout` instance to derived property. That too, seems a little silly.

**Can I avoid passing around the `pixel_layout` details, and instead use some kind of reference to the `pixel_type<...>` (sub)classes?**

**I tried using `enum`s**, because enums work as template argument & function argument. But I struggled to get from enum value (e.g. `rgba`) to pixel type property (e.g. 4 channels) at runtime & compile time in an idiomatic C++ way.

Also, enums as template arguments give far less useful diagnostics during compile error. For example, I get `image<(pixel_type)2>` rather than `image<rgba>` in compile error messages with clang. So this does not seem like a useful approach.

Comment: Interesting question, but I wonder if it lives better on code review?

Comment: Have you tried pointers as non type template parameters, where they point to `constexpr` instances of the layout?

Comment: No, what would that look like?

Comment: @molf Templates are compiled once for each combination of arguments. Passing pixel data in as template arguments is going to lead to there being a separate function compiled for every different color you create at compile time. This would lead to extreme program bloat if you used a lot of colors while compiling. So 1) I've misunderstood what you're asking for 2) This is a bad idea 3) This is a bad idea *but* you have a really compelling reason to do this. Whatever the case I'd like some clarification on *why* you're trying to do this.

Comment: Some operations have a different implementation based on the pixel format (or their properties) and are templated. Other operations are only available for particular types of pixel formats, and I'd like to make compilation fail for unsupported formats. Code with an implementation that does not depend on the pixel format is generally not templated, so no duplication there. So that's why I want both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using non-type reference template parameters might be a solution. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters . For example like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

enum class color_space : std::uint8_t { rgb, cymk, other };

// PIXEL LAYOUT
// Can be created/modified at runtime, but a predefined set of pixel_layouts
// exists for compile-time use.
struct pixel_layout {
    color_space space;
    std::uint8_t channels;
};

constexpr bool operator==(const pixel_layout& a, const pixel_layout& b) {
    return (a.space == b.space) && (a.channels == b.channels);
}
constexpr bool operator!=(const pixel_layout& a, const pixel_layout& b) {
    return (a.space != b.space) || (a.channels != b.channels);
}

// Predefined pixel_layout instances, for use as template arguments
// As static constexpr members of class, to make sure they have external linkage,
// required for use as reference template arguments.
struct default_pixel_layouts {
    static constexpr pixel_layout rgb{ color_space::rgb, 3 };
    static constexpr pixel_layout cymk{ color_space::cymk, 4 };        
};

// Definitions for the pixel_layouts
constexpr pixel_layout default_pixel_layouts::rgb;
constexpr pixel_layout default_pixel_layouts::cymk;


// PIXEL TYPE
// Takes pixel_layout reference as non-type template argument.
template<const pixel_layout& Layout>
struct pixel {
    static constexpr const pixel_layout& layout = Layout;

    // Because layout is constexpr, can use its members (e.g. channels),
    // for example as template argument.
    // Here size of pixel depends on number of channels in pixel_layout
    std::array<std::uint32_t, layout.channels> data;
};

// RGB and CYMK pixel_types as type aliases
using rgb = pixel<default_pixel_layouts::rgb>;
using cymk = pixel<default_pixel_layouts::cymk>;


// IMAGE
// Takes pixel type as template argument.
template<class PixelType>
class image {
public:
    using pixel_type = PixelType;
};


// TRANSFORM
// Takes pixel_layouts to transform from/to at runtime. Can for with the predefined
// ones, but also with new ones creates at runtime.
class transform {
private:
    const pixel_layout& from_;
    const pixel_layout& to_;

public:
    transform(const pixel_layout& from, const pixel_layout& to) :
    from_(from), to_(to) { }

    // Example: function working on an image
    template<class Image>
    void run(Image& img) {
        // Need to make sure that Image's pixel_layout (compile-time) matches
        // pixel_layout of the transform (runtime).
        if(Image::pixel_type::layout != from_)
            std::cout << "Wrong pixel type on input image" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "transforming..." << std::endl;
    }

};



int main() {
    image<rgb> rgb_img;
    image<cymk> cymk_img;

    // Transform from rgb to cymk
    transform tr(default_pixel_layouts::rgb, default_pixel_layouts::cymk);  
    tr.run(rgb_img); // ok
    tr.run(cymk_img); // error: input to run() must have rgb pixel_layout

    // Creating a new pixel_layout at runtime
    pixel_layout custom_layout = { color_space::other, 10 };
    transform tr2(custom_layout, default_pixel_layouts::cymk);  

    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/981e1b03b3b815c5

For the use cases where the `pixel_layout` is used at compile time, the different available `pixel_layout` instances need to be instantiated as global static constexpr objects.

`pixel_type` then instantiates to different classes, depending on the `pixel_layout&` given as template argument.

But they still can be used at runtime also.

Comment: [`constexpr` variables may be placed in a class as `static` variables to give them the `extern` linkage GCC expects of template parameters.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb77435d52fd6dc9)

Comment: Also a great solution, exactly the kind I was looking for.

Comment: Compared to other relevant solutions, this is the most elegant and comes closest to the specific question I asked. Thanks! I'll use some version of this idea in my code.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by making `rgb` and `rgba` etc empty classes:

```
struct rgb{};
struct rgba{};
struct cmyk{};
//...
```

Use these instead of enums for templates to get better diagnostics.

Then you can define a bunch of free `constexpr` functions that yield specific data, e.g.

```
constexpr uint8_t channels(rgb) { return 3; }
constexpr uint8_t channels(rgba) { return 4; }
```

This way you can offer the values that make sense for any given format. If a feature is not available for a certain format, just do not offer the overload.

You can construct the `pixel_layout` using such functions where needed, but I would imagine that classes like `transform` would just get a template constructor and gather the information they need without a `pixel_layout` intermediate.

I might be missing some use cases, so you might need to adjust this a bit, but I hope it helps.

Comment: How would you store (a reference to) the pixel format that can be used at runtime?

Comment: I would try to use those empty classes as long as possible. When you cannot use them because you cannot know the type at compile time, I would then translate them into `pixel_layout` (or similar, maybe more specialized types where it makes sense).
Another option would be type-erasure of course, if there are just a few functions need to call with those pixel-formats.
It depends on your scenarios. With the given information it is a bit hard for me to be more specific.

Comment: Ok. Could you maybe describe how your solution differs from mine conceptually? What advantages do the free functions have over `static constexpr` members like the ones I used? I'm not sure I understand that part.

Comment: Free functions have the benefit that you can choose _not_ to implement them for some formats if they don't make sense for them. That seemed to be one of the sore points with your current solution.

Answer (score 2):

Accoriding to you question:

**Can I avoid passing around the `pixel_layout` details?, and instead use some kind of reference to the `pixel_type<...>` (sub)classes?**

Yes you can using inheritance. You want to express a common interface at runtime so you need at least one data member pointing out the difference, as you already mentioned. The interface would look like this:

```
struct pixel_layout {
  virtual ~pixel_layout() = default;

  virtual color_space colorSpace() const = 0;
  virtual uint8_t channelCount() const = 0;
};
```

So far so fine. We could now pass around a pointer or reference to the `pixel_layout` implementation and use its information to the cost of two pointer. One pointing to the actual object and the other to the vtable.

Lets make an implementation.

```
template<typename _PixelT>
struct pixel_layout_implementation : pixel_layout {
  virtual color_space colorSpace() const override { return _PixelT::colorSpace(); }
  virtual uint8_t channelCount() const override { return _PixelT::channelCount(); }
};
```

Ok we got this. Notice my `pixel_type` declaration slightly differs.

```
template<color_space _SpaceT, uint8_t _ChannelC>
struct pixel_type {
  static constexpr color_space colorSpace() { return _SpaceT; }
  static constexpr uint8_t channelCount() { return _ChannelC; }
};
```

Now we can update your transform class.

```
struct transform {
  transfrom(const pixel_layout& from, const pixel_layout& to);
};
```

Finally we get in trouble. We have references to our `pixel_layout` and as long as they remain in memory its all fine but if we want to copy them we need to implement a deep copy and have again multiple instances. Before adressing this problem lets try to hide some complexity as implementation detail of `pixel_layout`.

```
struct pixel_layout {
private:
  struct concept_t {
    virtual ~concept_t () = default;

    virtual color_space colorSpace() const = 0;
    virtual uint8_t channelCount() const = 0;
  };

  template<typename _PixelT>
  struct concept_implementation_t : concept_t {
    virtual color_space colorSpace() const override { return _PixelT::colorSpace(); }
    virtual uint8_t channelCount() const override { return _PixelT::channelCount(); }
  };

  std::unique_ptr<const conept_t> pm_conceptImpl;

public:
  template<typename _PixelT>
  pixel_layout(_PixelT)
    : pm_conceptImpl{new concept_implementation_t<_PixelT>}
  {/* */}

  virtual color_space colorSpace() const { return pm_conceptImpl->colorSpace(); }
  virtual uint8_t channelCount() const { return pm_conceptImpl->channelCount(); }
};
```

This makes the inheritance invisible for the user of this class and the unique_ptr implicit removes copy construction and assignment. Additionally with `pixel_type` being an empty class the constructor allows us to write something like `pixel_layout rgb_layout = rgb();` without the leak of performance. Lets address the previous problem we did not solve yet. We are making new objects of `concept_implementation` for every `pixel_layout` each pointing to the same vtable. We can do better by sharing one object for each `color_space` over multiple instances.

```
template<typename _PixelT>
struct concept_implementation_t : concept_t {
  static const std::unique_ptr<const concept_t> shared_instance;

  virtual color_space colorSpace() const override { return _PixelT::colorSpace(); }
  virtual uint8_t channelCount() const override { return _PixelT::channelCount(); }
};
```

Now we only need to point to the `shared_instance` within our `pixel_layout`.

```
  const concept_t& pm_conceptImpl;

public:
  template<typename _PixelT>
  pixel_layout()
    : pm_conceptImpl{*concept_implementation_t<_PixelT>::shared_instance.get()}
  {/* */}
```

Putting all together we get the size of one pointer for each `pixel_layout` instance plus one pointer for each different supported `pixel_type`. Here is the final class and do not forget to put the static member initialization after the class definition.

```
struct pixel_layout {
private:
  struct concept_t {
    virtual ~concept_t () = default;

    virtual color_space colorSpace() const = 0;
    virtual uint8_t channelCount() const = 0;
  };

  template<typename _PixelT>
  struct concept_implementation_t : concept_t {
    static const std::unique_ptr<const concept_t> shared_instance;

    virtual color_space colorSpace() const override { return _PixelT::colorSpace(); }
    virtual uint8_t channelCount() const override { return _PixelT::channelCount(); }
  };

  const concept_t& pm_conceptImpl;

public:
  template<typename _PixelT>
  pixel_layout(_PixelT)
    : pm_conceptImpl{*concept_implementation_t<_PixelT>::shared_instance.get()}
  {/* */}

  virtual color_space colorSpace() const { return pm_conceptImpl.colorSpace(); }
  virtual uint8_t channelCount() const { return pm_conceptImpl.channelCount(); }
};

template<typename _PixelT>
const std::unique_ptr<const pixel_layout::concept_t> pixel_layout::concept_implementation_t<_PixelT>::shared_instance
  (new pixel_layout::concept_implementation_t<_PixelT>);
```

Comment: Great ideas to use polymorphism and a shared instance for each type. Exactly the kind of ideas I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt. Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems as if you can do most of what you want without the `pixel_layout` struct.

I would use the same implementation for `pixel_type`, so:

```
enum class color_space : uint8_t { rgb, rgba };

template <color_space ColorSpace, uint8_t Channels>
struct pixel_type {
  static constexpr color_space space    = ColorSpace;
  static constexpr uint8_t     channels = Channels;
};
```

But I would use alias's to define the different types, such as:

```
using rgb  = pixel_type<color_space::rgb, 3>;
using rgba = pixel_type<color_space::rgba, 4>;
```

I've found that using alias's gives easy(er) to decipher compiler messages (especially with clang), which is why I choose to use them here.

Now all I can see that the `layout` function is doing is wrapping the information you already have as template parameters (`color_space` and `uint8_t`) into a struct. However, you can access this information by using templates.

I'm going to assume that the `transform` class does something like this (please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
class transform {
  transform(const pixel_layout from, const pixel_layout to)
  : from(from), to(to) {}

  // Here *to* and *from* are stored so that to.space, from.space etc   
  // can be used for the transformation
};
```

But you can do this (quite nicely) by making the this transform class a template class, and pass the To and From transformation types as the template parameters. This has the benefit of allowing access to both the compile time template parameters and any runtime parameters, for example:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
class transform {
  transform(const From& from, const To& to) {
    // Access with From::channels, To::space etc, as the other transform class would have

    // Access any run-time parameters with to.rtime_param etc...
  }
}
```

Or, what I think is a better solution (but I don't know the specific use, so maybe not), to use a template function, and return the converted type, such as:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
To transform(const From& from, const To& to) {
  // Same access, From::channels
  // to.rtime_param 
}
```

Also, I considered that some transformations might be specific to the different pixel formats (rgb -> rgba might be different to rgb -> cmyk), so then I would just provide specialisations of the transform class or function to handle these specific cases.

Here is an example of possible usage with my solution:

```
rgb rgb_format;
rgba rgba_format;

// Using the transform struct 
transform rgb_to_rgba(rgb_format, rgba_format);

// Or similarly using the function
rgba transformed_rgb_format = transform(rgb, rgba);
```

Also, regarding the addition of properties, since this method has access to both compile time and run time properties, any additions to the pixel_type struct can be easily accessed at either compile time or run time.

One potential problem is the accessing of the static components outside of templated functions and class, since they need to be accessed through the type and not the instance.

```
rgb _rgb;

// Need to do this 
rgb::channels

// Rather than this 
_rgb::channels
```

But I think that's more of a readability problem than one which affects functionality.

[Simple Demo](http://cpp.sh/5eaih)

Comment: Yes, I can do most of what I want without `pixel_layout`: I can do the compile-time part without it. Your code seems to suggest that I should use the formats at compile time only? The problem I have with making the transform class templated is that most transformations will be determined at runtime anyway (through another library). Also, I have around 10 formats, that means up to 45 combinations for the transform class. Seems rather pointless.

Comment: No, in the demo I posted I showed access of the formats at runtime (by printing them). I see, so do you just need the format properties (color_type and the number of channels) for the runtime transformation? After thinking about it, I think that this is not the best solution. I will update later as I have another idea. Regardless of whether you use templates or not, will you not need to define the conversion functions for each combination anyway? Or is it possible to use the color_space and number of channels to somehow define a general function which will perform any transformation?

Comment: Each format has a number of properties (such as color space and number of channels, some others too I didn't mention), and I generally need all those properties for a transformation. Indeed I can access the properties at runtime in your example, but only by defining the type explicitly (through a template), which is pointless. Because by definition if I know the type of the format struct, I can access the properties at compile-time already.

Comment: A summary of my problem: some classes are templated over the pixel formats, and some are not: they need to store information about pixel formats in a generic way at runtime. I don't think templating everything will solve my problem realistically.

Comment: Okay I see, and agree that addressing through a template is pointless if you know the type. I suggested the template in the case that there is some general conversion from any format to any other format, in which case you would only need the single templated implementation of the function.  I will try to provide a better answer if I am able come up with something.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't aware that some classes were not templated with the format by need access to the information nonetheless. I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Use the template to set a member variable, and just change the variable at runtime if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with involves three data structures:

- **A type annotation enumeration**: `enum class pixel_type : char { };`
- **A union-type containing the pixel data**: `union pixel_data { };`
- **A struct to hold both, with a template parameter to specify the default type annotation**: `struct pixel{ };`

#### Compile-time / static:

- Use the template argument to establish the format type if you know it already.
- As a union, the `pixel_data` will be somewhat "unitless." If you already know the type, you can write functions that make the assumption that the data is in the correct representation. If you require a variable amount of memory to hold different pixel data formats, *this is clearly an issue* which is worth addressing explicitly. If this is so, modify the `pixel` class to parameterize on an internal implementation that deviates based on the size of the pixel memory representation.
- Use the `pixel` class at runtime for data that needs to be switched on type. Once done, you can unwrap the type annotation by using only its member `pixel_data` and then perform transformations on that. By separating the actual underlying data type and the metadata, it should be easier to perform data computation with masses of data without having to jump through member functions that belong only to the class, which can become troublesome should you decide to go multithreaded. Actually, I would say that you could also potentially include a lock in the pixel class if you're worried about that, or even apply it to the underlying data. It's up to you.
- Use `pixel_data` for computation within fields of code where the type can be assumed; otherwise, treat the `pixel` class as a sort of variant or optional data type.

#### Run-time / dynamic

- Use `pixel_data::unknown` for safety at runtime. If you so desire, you can create a sort of `apply` function that will act as a monadic guard to prevent `NULL`-like formats from getting through.
- Set the format in the `pixel` struct once you figure out the format.
- Once again, you can still remove the `pixel` data wrapper and throw away the type annotation once you so desire during computation.

#### Mass pixel storage and computation / transformation

- Create a sort of container class with the type annotation; this is to hold many data types which all have the same data type; wasting a byte per pixel to hold the pixel format is wasteful; if you want to a store a matrix, just store one byte for the entire matrix, and parameterize on the actual underlying data type again. This should be some sort of `pixel_matrix`, and the underlying memory structure should be sufficient to be able to easily apply SSE or other vectorized instructions without having to modify your data structures greatly at this point.
- Transformations can be done only with `pixel_data`. The switching logic should be make on the actual `pixel` or `pixel_matrix` data type, and the type stripped and reapplied before and after the transformation.

#### Summary

- Dyanmic data will encapsulate the static data layout, with a type annotation attached on, and the static data type is the template parameter to allow for different underlying unions or data types.
- Use the static data layout for transformations.
- Separation of different underlying static data layouts is important enough to warrant different types.
- A matrix-form of dynamic data and static data is important enough to save memory space and allow for vectorized instruction optimization.

Here is some very sparse code that I came up with: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76f31a9dd669a2fa

Comment: This is interesting, but doesn't really address my problem. I don't have the liberty to work with unions for pixel data. (AFAIK your code stores RGB data in 4 bytes, I can't have that). Internal data is passed around to various other libraries and needs to be in very specific formats. The `pixel_layout` I have in my code is used to describe these formats internally. You only refer to the color space and not much else. So I can't really apply this to my code.

Comment: @molf The point is more the design, not the use of a union. Use the template to setup the statically-known type or trait, and then set the variable at runtime if needed. If you so desire, use `constexpr` functions to encode traits that translate across types (e.g. `rgba` implies `size_t(4)` bytes or floats for your array). Represent the physical data as a struct or class and base your transformation type system on the underlying physical data. If you want additional type protection, perhaps it might be useful to use a class template with a parameter simply to take the trait.